# HTML5 server connection error when deployed in IIS

Tags: asp.net, html

I made a web application that fetches data from server then dispatch it to client browser using EventSource. It worked perfectly in localhost, however when I deployed the asp application to IIS, it logs an error to the console which says 'Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at http://hostname/SSEHandler.ashx.'

Here is my client side code for event source.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        if (window.EventSource == undefined) {
            alert("This browser doesn't support HTML5 Server Sent Events.");
            return;
        }

        var source = new EventSource('SSEHandler.ashx');

        $("#btnListen").click(function() {
            source.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
                data = data.slice(1);
                data.push(event.data);
                var strData = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    strData += data[i];
                    if (strData == "1") {
                        reloadTable();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

I viewed the page of http://hostname/SSEHandler.ashx and this was displayed:

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://hostname/SSEHandler.ashx
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

How will I solve this?

Comment: had you checked browser compatibility characteristics on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource#Browser_compatibility  ?

Comment: @JosefMadrid..does it mean it's not compatible with the current version of firefox?

Comment: All I see is _"Note: using EventSource is not supported by all browsers. Please check out the Browser compatibility section."_ May or may not these, seen by a compatibility problem. It just a step